# React pass child parent's width

Tags: reactjs

In the parent component, I get the width, which may differ depending on the device on which the application is opened:

```
const projectVisor = useRef()
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(projectVisor.current.offsetWidth)
}, [])
```

Now i want to pass this value to child in props

```
<ProjectItem
   width={width}
/>
```

But in the child, I always get 0. I think this is due to the fact that the useEffect runs at the same time as the child is rendered, which means that at the time the child is rendered, the value is 0. But I do not know how to avoid this.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using CSS only with 100% width? :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could work. It might just be a little bug in your code.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem like this:

```
{width !== 0 && <ProjectItem
   width={width}
/>}
```

Since I'm new to React, I ask more experienced users to take note if this solution may lead to unforeseen consequences.